# Для чего бывает нужен bing api_key?

Tags: dns

В настройках одной увидел возможность вставить некий bing api_key
Для чего он может быть полезен и как?
программы узнаёт субдомены

Comment: Bing.com - это поисковик, типа нашего Яндекса. Там и поискать надо, хотя и Яндекс легко справляется.

Comment: @Namer, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.